# EF, заполнение дб элементами со связью "многие к многим"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Есть модели

```
public class Server
{
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
public class Info
{
    public Info()
    {
        InfoGameMods = new List<InfoGameMode>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<InfoGameMode> InfoGameMods { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string[] GameMods
    {
        get
        {
            string[] gm = new string[InfoGameMods.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < gm.Length; i++)
                gm[i] = InfoGameMods[i].GameMode.Name;

            return gm;
        }
        set
        {
            ServerContext context = new ServerContext();
            foreach (var gm in value)
            {
                GameMode gameMode = context.GameMods.Where(_gm => _gm.Name == gm).FirstOrDefault();
                if (gameMode == null)
                {
                    gameMode = new GameMode { Name = gm };
                    context.GameMods.Add(gameMode);
                    InfoGameMode igm = new InfoGameMode
                    {
                        GameMode = gameMode,
                        Info = this
                    };
                    InfoGameMods.Add(igm);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
 public class InfoGameMode
{
    public int InfoId { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }

    public int GameModeId { get; set; }
    public GameMode GameMode { get; set; }
}
public class GameMode
{
    public GameMode()
    {
        InfoGameMods = new List<InfoGameMode>(); 
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<InfoGameMode> InfoGameMods { get; set; }
}
public class ServerContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Info> Info { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GameMode> GameMods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InfoGameMode> InfoGameMods { get; set; }

    public ServerContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<InfoGameMode>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.InfoId, t.GameModeId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<InfoGameMode>()
            .HasOne(igm => igm.Info)
            .WithMany(gm => gm.InfoGameMods)
            .HasForeignKey(igm => igm.InfoId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<InfoGameMode>()
            .HasOne(igm => igm.GameMode)
            .WithMany(info => info.InfoGameMods)
            .HasForeignKey(igm => igm.GameModeId);
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать это

```
 public void Info([FromBody]Server server)
    {

         db.Servers.Add(server);
         db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

но при запуске этого метода - SqlException:
"Cannot inserte explicit value for identity column un table "GameMods" when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF".

Как я понимаю, ошибка значит, что я пытаюсь явно присвоить индекс, в то время как "insert_identity off")

И, скорее всего дело в блоке set свойства GameMods модели Info(не уверен что его правильно написал).

А зачем там такой set? Надо сериализовать данный объект в json, а поле "GameMods" должно быть строкой, но при этом надо хранить сами "gamemods".
Получается я get-ом возвращаю массив строк. А вот set-ом надо как-то занести массив строк в бд, притом используется связь "многие к многим"(несколько gamemode на несколько info) с помощью введения доп модели InfoGameMode(EF **Core**). Как-то так)

Answer (score 0):

Может кому интересно будет)
Изменил блок set из Info.GameModes

```
public string[] GameMods
    {
        get
        {
            string[] gm = new string[InfoGameMods.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < gm.Length; i++)
                gm[i] = InfoGameMods[i].GameMode.Name;

            return gm;
        }
        set
        {
            foreach(var gm in value)
            {
                InfoGameMode igm = new InfoGameMode
                {
                    GameMode = new GameMode { Name = gm },
                    Info = this
                };
                InfoGameMods.Add(igm);
            }

        }
    }
```

и добавляю в бд таким образом:

```
public void Info([FromBody]Models.Server server)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < server.Info.InfoGameMods.Count; i++)
        {
            GameMode PUT_GameMode = server.Info.InfoGameMods[i].GameMode;
            GameMode DATA_GameMode = db.GameMods.FirstOrDefault(gm => gm.Name == PUT_GameMode.Name);
            if (DATA_GameMode != null)
                server.Info.InfoGameMods[i].GameMode = DATA_GameMode;
        }

        db.Servers.Add(server);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Как я понял, дело было в том, что при использовании `db.Servers.Add(server);` EF сам добавляет все связанные сущности, в то время как я сам это делал вручную, в итоге - конфликт по индексу. Также остался вопрос: как изменить данные в бд(тут наверное будет уместно сказать "заменить"), т.е. server в бд на server, который передается в метод, не меняя вручную каждое поле объекта, но это, думаю, уже другая тема.